# Set TextBox AccessText without an accompanying Label

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a series of textboxes in a usercontrol that do not have accompanying Labels.
I need to provide a means for a user to press Alt+(Some Key) to set focus to each of these textboxes.

If I want to use the built in WPF "AccessText" way of doing this, I would need to put a Label up next to each textbox, specify the content with an '_' character preceding the shortcut key, and specify the "Target" property of each Label to their respective Textbox.

Unfortunately in this case, there are no Labels for each textbox, and there will not be.

Is it possible to specify the AccessText shortcut key for a textbox, without a Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Handle key combinations press and after that focus on the TextBox :

*.xaml:

```
<UserControl Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Height="30" x:Name="txt1"/>
            <TextBox Height="30" x:Name="txt2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

*.cs

```
    public UserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void KeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        bool x = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.System);
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.System) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B))// Alt+B
        {
            txt2.Focusable = true;
            txt2.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        window.KeyDown += KeyDownEvent;
        txt1.Focusable = true;
        txt1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amine.  I had a feeling it was going to amount to something like this.  I was hoping to avoid having to handle the keypress events myself, and be able to set up key combinations in xaml.  But using your code, I can see a path to an attached property or behavior that would let me set this up in the markup.  I'm going to leave this unanswered for a bit though, in case someone else has something to add.